# SQL Server Nearest Date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of persons and a table of addresses. The persons table contains one instance of the person and the addresses table can contain multiple instances of a person. The persons table contains a date added field and the addresses table also contains a date added field. How do I find the nearest date before or on in the addresses table and then match that to the persons table so only one address is returned?

This is the SQL I have to do a basic join for an exact match:

```
select p.personid,a.addressid,p.dateadded,a.dateadded 
from persons p inner join a 
on p.personid = a.personid and
p.dateadded = a.dateadded
```

Edit: here are the persons table and addresses table:

```
personid    dateadded
1           01/01/2015
2           30/09/2014
3           01/08/2015

addressid   personid    dateadded
1           1           01/01/2015
2           2           16/02/2013
3           2           03/12/2013
4           3           19/05/2012
5           3           30/07/2015
6           3           07/09/2015
```

And here is the output I'm trying for:

```
personid    addressid   dateadded_person    dateadded_address
1           1           01/01/2015          01/01/2015
2           3           30/09/2014          03/12/2013
3           6           01/08/2015          30/07/2015
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve (maybe even with example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general approach that doesn't involve `top` or analytic functions.

Based on your comment I edited to change the logic that finds which address is the most relevant. This version takes the person then joins to `addresses` and takes only those addresses added before the person was. The `person_id` and maximum (latest) `dateadded` are captured. After that it's just another join again to `addresses` to pick up the single row you're interested in.

```
select ...
from
    persons as p
    inner join
    (
        select personid, max(a.dateadded) as dateadded
        from person as p inner join addresses as a on a.personid = p.personid
        where a.dateadded <= p.dateadded
        group by person
    ) as most_recent
        on most_recent.personid = p.personid
    inner join address as a
        on a.personid = p.person_id and a.dateadded = most_recent.dateadded
```

You might also like `cross apply`:

```
select ...
from
    persons as p
    cross apply (
        select max(a.dateadded) as most_recent from addresses as a
        where a.personid = p.personid and a.dateadded <= p.dateadded
    ) as mr
    inner join address as a
        on a.personid = p.person_id and a.dateadded = mr.most_recent
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain how it works? I'm trying to find the nearest date comparing both the personid and the date as opposed to the maximum date of a personid in the address table. Apologies if I've misunderstood the solution.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your explanation and solution.